# UDP Index out of range

Tags: sockets, udp

I am trying to figure out why the client component of the array below is out of range. I know this happens when the element of an array that you are trying to access doesn't exist but I am new to Socket Programming and trying to write my first UDP script but not sure how to deal with it.

**Client side code causing error at the args[0]:**

```
class EmployeeUDPClient{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(args[0],2055);   //Line causing error
        IPEndPoint ep = null;
        while(true){
            Console.Write("Name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            if(name == "") break;
            byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
            udpc.Send(sdata,sdata.Length);
            byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
            string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
            Console.WriteLine(job);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the server side code which runs fine:**

```
class EmployeeUDPServer{
    public static void Main(){
        UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(2055);
        Console.WriteLine("Server started, servicing on port 2055");
        IPEndPoint ep = null;
        while(true){
            byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
            string name = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
            string job = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[name];
            if(job == null) job = "No such employee";
            byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(job);
            udpc.Send(sdata,sdata.Length,ep);
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why I get this error? I am running the 2 scripts on the same computer so could that be the reason?

Comment: Are you actually passing any `args[]` to function `Main()`?

Comment: No. I know that in order for args[0] to work I have to pass something to Main() but I don't know in this case what I am suppose to pass...Perhaps the string from Server script is suppose to be sent to Client script but shouldn't Client script run atleast to accept the string of text from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are not passing any arguments to the Main() function within your client class.

Change line:

```
UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(2055);
```

To:

```
string[] host = new string[1];
host[0] = "127.0.0.1";
UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(host);
```

Comment: so I should just make a random IP for each client that I have? Keep the same port for all the clients and the server?

Comment: your server should use it's own connection to listen for clients.. when something tries to connect to it, you should make a new instance of your client class (on a different port), and use that to accept the connection; leaving the original server client/connection free to listen for more clients.

Comment: Sorry - I've just realised you're using UDP doh! It's connectionless, so you should only neeed to use the one - listen on 127.0.0.1 and that should be it I think